# How to make parallel HTTP requests to Django within the same session?

Tags: python, ajax, django, nginx, uwsgi

Lets say I have a webpage with 3 tables which I load through ajax. I make 3 async ajax calls, but since they are coming from the same session, they are actually run one after another on the server, not in parallel as I would like.

I don't need to worry about concurrent data corruption, the 3 requests are completely independent read only requests, I only need the session to verify if the user is still logged in.

So the question is: how do I make the real parallel http requests on nginx + uwsgi + django stack for the same user session? If it's indeed not possible, what would be the best way to make it possible? I searched everywhere for any hints, and I see people saying it is a limitation of: nginx, uwsgi, django, python, a browser, a programmer, without any real answers how to solve it.

Comment: I wasn't aware of any such limitation, and I don't get it actually. Three concurrent ajax calls will be run one after the other on the server? Why is that? What is going to queue them? Could you provide a reference?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides if you make the first call to sleep on the backend for a while, the rest won't return until that sleeping one is processed. This happens only if all requests are coming from the same user, if you point second user to the sleeping backend it won't delay the rest.

Comment: I don't believe it's a common problem, and it probably depends on your setup. Maybe you are using some kind of middleware that does this. Maybe you are using some transaction stuff that results in the database locking. Maybe whatever. So, as usual, you need to provide the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?  I have the opposite question.  How to make sure they are processed sequentially?

Comment: So five years later I decided to get to the bottom of it and turns out it was `processes=1` setting in uwsgi config.